# Why does using flex wrap break the height of an item containing large images?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have set up a simple page using a container with Flexbox enabled and 2 child divs.

Sizes are set using view width and view height for the container.

Child divs are set to a 600px and 400px width using css flex shorthand.

A large image has been added to child one and resized to 100%.

This works perfectly until `flex-wrap: wrap` is enabled on the container.

Then the height of the children are suddenly to big.

Is there a way to fix this behaviour?

Below is my code.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.flex-container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex-item1 {
  flex: 1 1 600px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: coral;
}

.flex-item2 {
  flex: 1 1 400px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
}

.image {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item1">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000/2000" class="image" alt="image" />
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item2">
    <h1>Header 1</h1>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add this to your code:

```
.flex-item1 {
   height: 100%;
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.flex-container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex-item1 {
  flex: 1 1 600px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: coral;
  height: 100%; /* new */
}

.flex-item2 {
  flex: 1 1 400px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
}

.image {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item1">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000/2000" class="image" alt="image" />
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item2">
    <h1>Header 1</h1>
  </div>
```

---

With a single line flex container (`flex-wrap: nowrap`), the `height: 100%` on the container is recognized by the `height: 100%` on the image (2 levels down).

With a multi-line flex container (`flex-wrap: wrap`), the `height: 100%` on the container isn't inherited by the image. The percentage height chain breaks. So you need to add `height: 100%` to the middle link (the flex item), for the layout to work in both cases.

Not exactly sure why this happens. Would have to research it.

Comment: This fixed the problem! Thank you, I was going crazy figuring this out. Definitely going to research this now I know what the problem was.